# I'm working on a C++ application to convert binary to decimal numbers

Tags: c++, binary

i'm working on a C++ application, to convert binary's to decimal numbers, and currently i have a working application, but the problem arises now that it have to have intermediate results.

Since i know the conversation on paper, and i know the basics of C++ i didn't believe this would be very difficult, but i need some help, i don't need you to write it for me, i need someone to help point me in the right direction, so i can solve it by myself.
The intermediate results would have to be something like this if i convert 1100 to decimal:

```
--------------- 
0 * 2⁰ = 0
0 * 2¹ = 0
1 * 2² = 4
1 * 2³ = 8
-----------------
```

which would end up being 12 (8 + 4 + 0 + 0 = 12)

the code so far can be found here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fP2GfT5Pzq/
and below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int binary_to_decimal(long long);

int main()
{
    long long number;
    cout << "Please enter the Binary you wish to convert: " << endl;
    cin >> number;

    cout << "In binary : '" << number << "' In decimal: '" << binary_to_decimal(number) << "'" << endl;
}

int binary_to_decimal(long long number)
{
    int decimal_number = 0, i = 0, remainder;
    while (number != 0)
    {
        remainder = number % 10;

        // Number = number divided by then
        number /= 10;

        // decimal_number = decimal_number + remainder to the power of 2
        decimal_number += remainder * pow(2, i);
        ++i;
    }
    return decimal_number;
}
```

Hope you can help :)

Comment: I think you should use an array of char to store the binary code rather than using "long long" type. That way you can just loop through the array and convert each character into integer and perform your algorithm.

Comment: My suggestion (assuming you can't use `std::stoi` because this is class work?) is to read in the original value as a `std::string`, then reverse-iterate through the characters. This gives the benefit of allowing you to sanity check the input (using `find_first_not_of`), and allows larger inputs.

Comment: @John Yes it was class work, but voluntary so the teacher didn't compile it on his machine, so i could use C++11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print intermediate results, then you are very close. Since you are very close, the only hint I could give you is: you need to print stuff inside that `while` loop. Here's the code, you don't have to look at it if you don't want to :)

```cpp
cout << "---------------" << endl;
while (number != 0)
{
    remainder = number % 10;

    number /= 10;

    int digit = remainder * pow(2,i);
    decimal_number += digit;

    cout << remainder << " * (2^" << i << ") = " << digit << endl;
    ++i;
}
cout << "---------------" << endl;
```

Comment: BTW, the `pow` function is for floating point.  Try using the expression `1 << i` instead.

Comment: Also, manipulating digits may be easier by inputting the number as a string.  You can convert the digits by:  `int value = number_as_string[i] - '0';`.

Comment: Since `number_as_string` is a string/an array of characters, `number_as_string[i]` retrieves the `i`-th character in the [array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-c-cpp/)